# Conditionally add character to the beginning of a string in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame like this:

```
Date
 9/02/2019
12/08/2019
 8/06/2019
```

I want to add a `0` in infront of dates that are in single digit. I want it to be like this:

```
Date
09/02/2019
12/08/2019
08/06/2019
```

I am using this RegEx and the string manipulation. The string manipulation by itself works, but when I try to work it out with the RegEx, it doesn't yield anything.

```
if row['Date'] == r'[\d]{1}/[\d]{1,2}/[\d]{4}':
   row['blah'] = '0' + row['Date']
   print(row['blah'])
else:
   pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and convert it to string using [`Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

print(df)
         Date
0  09/02/2019
1  12/08/2019
2  08/06/2019
```

Comment: Thanks @Sandeep I tried this. Actually the format is dd/mm/yyyy. So i used `('%d/%m/%Y')`. It outputs `06/08/2019` instead of `08/06/2019`. any idea why?

Comment: @Bharath Check the update.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks man.